# Passport authentication middleware res not defined

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have below code

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'username',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true
},
 function(req,username, password, next) {
     console.log('req' + req.body.socialID );
   var res ="";
  userController.ValidateLogin(req,res,function(userDetails){
    console.log('g d' + userDetails);
    req.user = userDetails;
    return next(null,userDetails);
    });


 }));
```

I have returing response from usercontroller.validatelogin if there is any error like

```
return res.send({ Status:403, Msg: 'There was a problem while fetching the record' });
```

It says res.send not a method.
How to pass res in usercontroller.validatelogin to return response.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you use passport strategy you should return `done()`. In there you can pass the user if your user is validated. for example if you checked that no user is in the DB and then you created it successfully you can do

```
return done(null, user, { message: "Hello user from db" });
```

and if a username was taken you pass false for user:

```
return done(null, false, { message: "User exists . Try again" });
```

then on your route you can do

```
app.get("/route", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate(strategyName, function (err, user, info) { 

 /*now you have access to res and now you can do if condition to do 
  stuff when there is a user don't forget to do req.login() */ 

})
```

To answer your question there is no adding `res` in `passport.use` I think they only have `passReqToCallback` that is why you can only use `req`

Comment: yes I can return but how can I return status and message

Comment: you do that in the route. the message is in `info` check to see if `user` is false or not and you could do res.send(info). `done` , the callback automatically puts the message in `info`.

Comment: your fourth parameter in  `req,username, password, next`should be `done` not `next`. If you don't use `done` passport won't authenticate anything as per my experience. It simply won't work.